# Xamarin.Forms: how to automatically hide first CollectionView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, scroll, scrollbar, collectionview

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms app** that will contain a page with 2 ***CollectionView*** items:

- an **horizontal *CollectionView*** that will display events
- a **vertical *CollectionView*** that will display posts

I would like that the first list is progressively hidden as soon as the user starts to scroll on the second list.

We can found this behaviour on a [sample](https://github.com/syncfusion/essential-ui-kit-for-xamarin.forms/blob/c572069555713388834156a254f1a451903d7ea3/EssentialUIKit/Views/Catalog/ArticleListPage.xaml) from **Syncfusion**: but they use a ***SfRotator*** as control for the horizontal list:

[image]

I've tried to reproduce the same behaviour on my page, but it doesn't work as expected. My horizontal list is not hidden until I scroll vertically on this first list itself. If I scroll on the second vertical list, the first list is still visible:

[image]

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:NewsViewModel" 
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Padding="16" Spacing="16">
                <CollectionView x:Name="EventsListView"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Events}"
                                HeightRequest="250"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                           ItemSpacing="20" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <ctrl:ShadowFrame BackgroundColor="Red">
                               <StackLayout x:DataType="model:Event" >
                                   <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                   <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                               </StackLayout>
                           </ctrl:ShadowFrame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <CollectionView x:Name="NewsListView"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding News}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                           ItemSpacing="20" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <ctrl:ShadowFrame>
                               <StackLayout x:DataType="model:News">
                                   <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                   <Label Text="{Binding Date}" />
                                   <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                               </StackLayout>
                           </ctrl:ShadowFrame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

***=> Is there a way to achieve this?***

Answer (score 1):

Quick reminder that you **Shouldn't use Scrollable Elements inside other Scrollable Element**, it usually breaks how both work, [Quoting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/listview-inside-scrollview-xamarinforms-workaround#:%7E:text=Xamarin%20doesn%27t%20recommend%20using,scrolling%2C%20like%20ListView%20and%20WebView.):

> Xamarin doesn't recommend using the ListView, WebView, or ScrollView
> inside a ScrollView. [Microsoft Xamarin.Forms Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview)
> says that ScrollViews should not be nested. In addition, ScrollViews
> should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, like
> ListView and WebView.

### And this is what happening:

The **`ScrollView`** isn't *actually* scrolling, the **Vertical `CollectionView`** is the one giving the Illusion that the page is scrolling, meaning that the **Horizontal** one is always on top.

### How to fix it?

To fix this, you should remove the **Vertical `CollectionView`** and use some kind of Repeater View, this [Post](https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-create-repeaterview-in-your-xamarin-forms-app/) will guide you on how to achieve it.