# ScrollView Inside another ScrollView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I am developing an app, using Xamarin Forms. In this App I want the user to be able to scroll The entire Page Vertically, but only a part of the page vertically. See [this image](https://i.postimg.cc/8CT7PHf8/scrollview-question-stackoverflow.png) for a visual reference. I read on the Xamarin [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview) Documentation, that

> ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition, ScrollView objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView.

So, how can I achieve this without nesting two ScrollViews? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: your image says you want to scroll the inner container horizontally - if that is correct then nesting might work.  You will need to try and see.

Comment: Having nested ScrollViews but with different Orientations is not the end of the world, the real problem happens when you have 2+ with the same orientation, if you actually need to list content while being able to scroll through the page, you can follow my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63957734/8182493)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to have 2 nested scroll viewers in Xamarin.Forms.

Notice how it says 'scroll viewers ***should not*** be nested, this means that it is certainly possible but it is not recommended. I think nested scroll viewers creates a bad user-experience and makes for a clunky app, especially for Xamarin.Forms; but again, here is a demonstration of a nested scroll viewer:

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I think once you've played around with nested scroll viewers it should be easy for you to implement what you want. I would recommend using a grid with column and row definitions with your desired measurements.

If I've answered your question, please mark this as the correct answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work like intended. I retried the code, like your example and it then worked as I wanted it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to your screenshot, i make a code sample for your reference.

**Xaml:**

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="150" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Accent">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A1"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A2"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A3"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A4"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A5"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A6"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A7"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A8"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A9"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="A10"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <Label HeightRequest="150" Text="Elem1"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <Label HeightRequest="150" Text="Elem2"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <Label HeightRequest="150" Text="Elem3"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <Label HeightRequest="150" Text="Elem4"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <Label HeightRequest="150" Text="Elem5"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B1"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B2"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B3"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B4"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B5"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B6"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B7"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B8"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B9"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                    <Label
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Text="B10"
                        WidthRequest="50" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]